# Where are programming tasks in scrum detailed at?

Tags: agile, task

When you have sprint task in Scrum, where do you put how you want to program something?  For example, say I am making a tetris game and I want to build the part of the game that tracks the current score and a high score table.  I have my feature, my user story and my task, but now I want to talk about how to design it.

Is that design something that is recorded on the sprint somewhere as to how to do that or is that just somethign the programmer figures out.  Do you put do task x use database such and such, create these columns, etc.?  If not, do you record that at all?  Is that what trac is for?  I don't mean too high level design.

I touched on it here:  [Where in the scrum process is programming architecture discussed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009688/where-in-the-scrum-process-is-programming-architecture-discussed)

but my current question is later in the project after the infrastructure.  I'm speaking more about the middle now.  The actual typing in the code.  Some said they decide along the way, some team-leads.  Is this is even documented anywhere except in the code itself with docs and comments?

edit:  does your boss just say, okay, you do this part, I don't care how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I submit tasks to my programming team, the description usually takes the shape of a demo, a description on how the feature is shown in order to be reviewed.

How the task will be implemented is decided when we evaluate the task. The team members split the task in smaller items. If a design is necessary, the team will have to discuss it before being able to split it. If the design is too complex to be done inside this meeting, we will simply create a design task, agile/scrum doesn't force how this should be done (in a wiki, in a doc, in your mind, on a napkin, your choice) aside for saying as little documentation as possible. In most case the design is decided on a spot, after a bit of debate, and the resulting smaller tasks are the description of how things will be done.

Also, sometimes the person doing it will make discoveries along the way that change the design and so, the way to work on it. We may then thrash some cards, make new ones. The key is to be flexible.

Answer (score 3):

There can be architectural requirements in addition to user-specified requirements that can muddy this a bit.  Thus, one could have a, "You will use MVP on this," that does limit the design a bit.

In my current project, aside from requirements from outside the team, the programmer just figures it out is our standard operating procedure.  This can mean crazy things can be done and re-worked later on as not everyone will code something so that the rest of the team can easily use it and change it.

Code, comments and docs cover 99% of where coding details would be found.  What's left, if one assumes that wikis are part of docs?

Comment: thank you.  i guess i am making it more difficult than it has to be.

Answer (score 2):

**Scrum says absolutely nothing about programming tasks. Up to you to work that out...**

Scrum doesn't necessarily have anything explicitly to do with programming - you can use it to organise magazine publication, church administration, museum exhibitions... it's a management technique not explicitly a way of managing software development.

**If you do extreme programming inside scrum, you just break your user stories for the iteration down into task cards, pair up and do them.**

Answer (score 0):

You do what you need to do. Avoid designing everything up front, but if there are things you already **know** will not change, then just capture them. However, corollary to YAGNI is that you don't try to capture too much too soon as the understanding of what is needed will likely change before someone gets to do it.

I think your question sounds more like you should be asking *who*, not *when* or *where*. The reason Agile projects succeed is that they understand that people are part of the process. Agile projects that fail seem to tend to favor doing things according to someone's idea of "the book" and not understanding the people and project they have. If you have one senior team lead and a bunch of junior developers, then maybe the senior should spend more of their time on such details (emphasis on maybe). If you have a bunch of seniors, then leaving these to the individual may be a better idea. I assume you don't have any cross-team considerations. If you do, then hashing out some of the details like DB schema might need to come early if multiple teams depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you (as team member) feels the need to talk about design, to so some design brainstorming with other team members, **then just do it**. About the how, many teams will just use a whiteboard and brain juice for this and keep things lightweight which is a good practice IMHO.

Personally, I don't see much value in writing down every decision and detail in a formalized document, at least not in early project phases. Written documents are very hard to maintain and get deprecated pretty fast. So I tend to prefer face to face communication. Actually, written documents should only be created if they're really going to be used, and in a very short term. This can sound obvious but I've seen several projects very proud of their (obsolete) documentation but without any line of code. That's just ridiculous. In other words, write extensive documentation as late as possible, and only if someone value it (e.g. the product owner).